# Unexpected behavior with FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-wifi, android-location

I am currently developing an application which requires location of the user at the usage time.

My problem is as follows, I am using FusedLocationApi and everything seems to be working fine with phones below android 4.3 version. All wi-fi, 3g and gps returns a location update. However, with Samsung S4, Note3 (newer phones with android 4.4+ version) I cannot get location update using Wi-fi or 3g but only get them using GPS. Here is my code snippet

```
 private ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Google Play Services connected, requesting location updates", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, mLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
};

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Found location from: " + location.getProvider(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationListener);
        new AsyncFetchAddress().execute(location);
    }
};

private OnConnectionFailedListener mConnectionFailedListener = new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Connection to Play Services failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

And this is api connect

```
if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ctx) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Google Play Services avaliable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mCtx)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Google Play Services not available, canceling location update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Google Play services are available and it requests location updates (debugged with toasts)

What do you think my problem is? Why it will not work on wi-fi or 3g but only gps with newer phones (probably something to do with android version, 4.4.2 are on these phones)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that in the location settings of your 4.4.2 phone you've enabled "high accuracy"/"Battery saving"? The default is GPS only.

Comment: Yes, I have selected High Accuracy under location modes

Comment: After I have digged in a bit more, i saw it was changing location settings all the time (strange) but I mark your comment as accepted now. Thanks.